# Dropbox API v2 get_current_user

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am migrating from API v1 to API v2 and have this problem here.
First i receive the token with this request:

https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token

Then i call

https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account

adding "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" header to get user's display name, but it fails every time with this message:

{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account}

The same code with API v1 calls worked just fine. Is there anything i missed? Thanks

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210658986-API-v2-get-current-user-error ]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a SDK like [CloudRail](https://cloudrail.com/unified-cloud-storage-api/)? Then it would be just a function call like documented [here](https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-android-sdk/wiki/Usage#interfaces-cloudstorage-functions-getusersloginidentifier)

Comment: becasuse it doesn't have all the cloud storages i need and has a lot that i don't need. it would be an overkill. plus i already had api v1 working